# Can a database exception contain the password used in the connection string?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, exception, database-connection

Can a standard database exception (ADO.NET or Entity Framework) contain the password after running `.ToString()` on it?

I'm mostly interested in MS SQL and Postgres databases.

I'd like to be sure I won't get the password in logs, which I create on each "ToStringed" database exception.

Comment: I dont think so,even at the time of login failure,exception will just log details about state of the exception,but not password info